# Override constants within a python package

Tags: python, package, constants, openpifpaf

I am using this python package for a personal project: https://openpifpaf.github.io/intro.html
I have installed it with pip install openpifpaf.
I am trying to train a new model with openpifpaf.train command, but I need different constant values that are specified within this file inside the package: https://github.com/vita-epfl/openpifpaf/blob/main/src/openpifpaf/plugins/wholebody/constants.py

Any way I can override these values, short of pulling the repo and modifying the file there?

Btw, changing the constants is the way the documentation recommends for training. Wish it was properly parameterized.

If I can't find a way to do this, I will probably just pull the repo and change the source.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the value of `SCALE_FACE` from 1.05 to 2 in the file you linked, you can do so in the following way:

```
import openpifpaf
openpifpaf.plugins.wholebody.constants.SCALE_FACE = 2
```

Comment: I am still seeing the same error which at least initially I thought was  indicative of openpifpaf.train using the default values inside constants.py. I filed a bug here: https://github.com/openpifpaf/openpifpaf/issues/592, but no response yet. But upvoting your answer since it addresses the question I asked. Thank you.